# qt-ruby and custom widgets on QGraphicsScene

Tags: ruby, qt, qtruby

Im using qt-ruby and i want to add an Widget to the QGraphicsScene, using addWidget().
In return, I get an QGraphicsProxyWidget.

Later, when the user clicks the GraphicsScene, use itemAt() to find the Widget that was clicked. But itemAt() returns an QGraphicsItem.

How can i match the QGraphicsProxyWidget to the QGraphicsItem?

I solved this problem in C++ using qgraphicsitem_cast, but that seems to be unavailable in qt-ruby.

Please help!